# Custom iPhone App That Adds Icon/Weblink to Desktop

Tags: iphone

I need to create a super basic script package that will install like a regular iPhone app but only puts an icon on the user's desktop that links to a mobile website that I specify. I'm a PHP developer and am slightly familiar with Java but simply need a boost due to time constraints. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a mobile friendly website and invite users to add it to their home screen.  A nice way to do this is found here:

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

[image: Add to Home Screen]

The iPhone will display a nice icon if your site has a tag like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/myicon.png"/>
```

More info here:

http://woorkup.com/2010/08/06/how-t-custom-home-screen-and-web-clip-icons/

Answer (score 0):

In your application delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourwebsite.com"]]; 
}
```

That's all!

P.S.

Okay, I've made step-by-step  instructions for you:
1) Open Xcode
2) Make a new project (file->new->new project -> Empty application)
3) Open AppDelegate.m (name may vary (depends on XCode version), so look for just ***Delegate.m )
4) Replace

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {  
//...everything...
}
```

With what I've wrote above. (that is to say replace contents of the class method with another method which just opens URL)

Comment: This might be what I need - can you recommend a complete but basic script I can use to implement this code? Thanks!